# Google Cloud SQL Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL 2nd Gen instance that last reported statistics (ie- Storage Usage, CPU Usage, etc...) at 10:09 this morning (~5.5 hours ago)

In the 'Operations' tab I can see:

`Date/Time | Type | Status
6 Feb 2017, 10:11:03 | Update | Done.`

I am currently unable to connect to the instance from my application or remotely. Fortunately it is a test environment that has issues.

We do not have a Google Support Package. What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Contact Google Support. They are the only ones that will be able to help you resolve this.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a support package and I'll be damned if I can find a free contact.

* Restarted the instance. Waited. Nothing
* Ran an export in the hope that I can import directly to a new instance - after export completed, it came back online.

Comment: Well, this is the price you have to pay for running production systems without adequate support.

Comment: "Fortunately it is a test environment that has issues." - this was a test environment, not a production environment.

Comment: Well, this is the price you have to pay for running systems without adequate support.  <--- fixed it. :) Honestly though, if this is a test system, just kill it and rebuild. This is something you should have automated anyway.

Comment: Is this solved now? OP, could you write a self-answer explaining how it was solved?